# rendering HTML from javascript iteration to print table row not working with TypeError

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Learning from [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rJesac0_Ftw). I am trying to render HTML of this sensor data:

```
{
    "arduino": [{
        "location": "outdoor",
        "temperatureInC": "18.30",
        "temperatureInF": "64.94",
        "humidity": "61"
    }, {
        "location": "drawingRoom",
        "temperatureInC": "25.10",
        "temperatureInF": "77.18",
        "humidity": "40.80"
    }]
}
```

and using this function to print HTML:

```
function renderHTML(data)
{
   var htmlString = "<table style='width:100%'><tr><th>Location</th><th>Temperature</th><th>Humidity</th></tr>";
   for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
      console.log(i);
      htmlString += "<tr><td>"+ data[i].location + "</td><td>" + data[i].temperatureInC + "&deg;C/ " + data[i].temperatureInF + "&deg;F </td> <td> " + data[i].humidity + "</td></tr>";
   htmlString += "</table>"
   console.log(htmlString);
   sensorDataContainer.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', htmlString);
   }
}
```

but two problems are happening,

1. it only prints the first item of iteration i.e. the outdoor
2. secondly it is giving the below error:

> TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating
>   'sensorDataContainer.insertAdjacentHTML')

I am bamboozled what is going on in here ! what am I missing ?

Comment: FYI: `htmlString += "</table>"` inside the loop is going to prematurely close your table, and cause invalid html syntax after that causing the browser to make multiple tables

Comment: Is `data` the whole object that you show at the begining or the array at `arduino`, if its the entire object, you need to do `data.arduino` in the loop

Comment: thanks from pythonista, I was supposed to remember the parentheses

Comment: Where in said code did you declare `sensorDataContainer`?

Comment: write in the beginning

Comment: thanks got it , I was declaring `var sensorDataContainer = document.getElementById("displaySensorData");` in a different function that was pulling the `json`, beginner , excuse my for my sillness

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you are seeing the first row only because you're not closing the `for` loop correctly try this instead:

```
function renderHTML(data)
{
   var htmlString = "<table style='width:100%'><tr><th>Location</th><th>Temperature</th><th>Humidity</th></tr>";
   for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
      console.log(i);
      htmlString += "<tr><td>"+ data[i].location + "</td><td>" + data[i].temperatureInC + "&deg;C/ " + data[i].temperatureInF + "&deg;F </td> <td> " + data[i].humidity + "</td></tr>";
   }
   htmlString += "</table>"
   console.log(htmlString);

   sensorDataContainer.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', htmlString); 
}
```

Second, you are using `sensorDataContainer` without intializing it, you need to initialize it first.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the last three lines outside of the `for` loop.

```
function renderHTML(data) {
    var htmlString = "<table style='width:100%'><tr><th>Location</th><th>Temperature</th><th>Humidity</th></tr>";
    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        console.log(i);
        htmlString += "<tr><td>"+ data[i].location + "</td><td>" + data[i].temperatureInC + "&deg;C/ " + data[i].temperatureInF + "&deg;F </td> <td> " + data[i].humidity + "</td></tr>";
    }
    htmlString += "</table>";
    console.log(htmlString);
    sensorDataContainer.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', htmlString);
}
```